# PHP MySQL query for insert with Concatenation assignment variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I was facing the problem with php insert multiple image and the only post id to the database.
In database I have image table and post table, when I upload multiple image the image will store in image table with the current post id.

The problem is the insert syntax is wrong, because the

> $insertValuesSQL

is from for each with using `.=` concatenation assignment to upload the image.

The thing is for I was to add addtional post id easy for me to get the image from which post id, so I have to insert with two thing which is `$insertValuesSQL` and the `$last_id` from the post id.

Can someone help me to correct the syntax and able to upload the image with the post id? Aprreciate and thank you.

**Error at:**

```
 $insert = $conn->query("INSERT INTO test (file_name, post_id) VALUES $insertValuesSQL,$last_id");
```

**PHP full code:**

```
$targetDir = "uploads/";
$allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif');

$statusMsg = $errorMsg = $insertValuesSQL = $errorUpload = $errorUploadType = '';
if(!empty(array_filter($_FILES['submit-image']['name']))){
    foreach($_FILES['submit-image']['name'] as $key=>$val){
        // File upload path
        $fileName = basename($_FILES['submit-image']['name'][$key]);
        $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;

        // Check whether file type is valid
        $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
            // Upload file to server
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["submit-image"]["tmp_name"][$key], $targetFilePath)){
                // Image db insert sql
                $insertValuesSQL .= "('".$fileName."'),";
            }else{
                $errorUpload .= $_FILES['submit-image']['name'][$key].', ';
            }
        }else{
            $errorUploadType .= $_FILES['submit-image']['name'][$key].', ';
        }
    }

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
        echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
        if(!empty($insertValuesSQL)){
            $insertValuesSQL = trim($insertValuesSQL,',');
            // Insert image file name into database
            $insert = $conn->query("INSERT INTO test (file_name, post_id) VALUES $insertValuesSQL,$last_id");
            if($insert){
                $errorUpload = !empty($errorUpload)?'Upload Error: '.$errorUpload:'';
                $errorUploadType = !empty($errorUploadType)?'File Type Error: '.$errorUploadType:'';
                $errorMsg = !empty($errorUpload)?'<br/>'.$errorUpload.'<br/>'.$errorUploadType:'<br/>'.$errorUploadType;
                $statusMsg = "Files are uploaded successfully.".$errorMsg;
            }else{
                $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

}else{
    $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
}
```

Adding one more

if I using the code below :

```
                $insert = $conn->query("INSERT INTO test (file_name) VALUES $insertValuesSQL");
```

It successful to upload multiple image but there no post id for the image

**Reference from :**
https://www.codexworld.com/upload-multiple-images-store-in-database-php-mysql/

Comment: @user3783243 Yes, that one is insert post query, so after succesful insert post, i get the last id for upload the image with the id

Comment: Output the actual query, it looks like its going to be pretty mangled. I think it'd come out as `INSERT INTO test (file_name, asd) VALUES ('filename'),,last_id_value` which isn't going to work. Use the `mysqli` error reporting function so you get the actual error. This also is open to SQL injections. I'd recommend doing this with parameterized queries.

Comment: @user3783243 sorry my bad,  I was typed wrong `test (file_name, asd) `

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection. Don’t ignore the advice to use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `$last_id` into every list of values being inserted, not as a separate parameter. But you can't do this because you're creating `$insertValuesSQL` before you set `$last_id`.

You can move the loop that creates `$insertValuesSQL` to after you set `$last_id`, but another way is to use MySQL's built-in function `LAST_INSERT_ID()`:

```
$insertValuesSQL .= "('".$fileName."', LAST_INSERT_ID()),";
```

Then you can take `$last_id` out of the later `INSERT` query:

```
$insert = $conn->query("INSERT INTO test (file_name, post_id) VALUES $insertValuesSQL");
```

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` can create race condition though, can't it?

Comment: No, it's exactly the same as `mysqli_insert_id()`. They both get the last ID inserted by the current connection.